# Match any word of a List/Array in a Sentence java

Tags: java, regex

I have an `List` of word like below

```
List<String> forbiddenWordList = Arrays.asList("LATE", "S/O", "SO", "W/O", "WO");
```

How can I understand a `String` Contains any one of the word of the `List`. like....

```
String name1 = "Adam Smith";      // false (not found)
String name2 = "Late H Milton";   // true  (found Late)
String name3 = "S/O Furi Kerman"; // true  (found S/O)
String name4 = "Conl Faruk";      // false (not found)
String name5 = "Furi Kerman WO";  // true  (found WO)
```

Regular Expression highly appreciated.

Comment: I've add a pattern solution which allows to keep the List option to add words and do not need to add by hand the words to pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have got a Solution myself with the help all of you....

```
    String regex = String.join("|", forbiddenWordList.stream().map(word -> "\\b" + word + "\\b").collect(Collectors.toList()));
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    System.out.println(pattern.matcher(name).find());
```

The word boundary (`\\b`) helps to find exact word, not the matched text.
Thanks everyone for helping.

Answer (score 9):

```
boolean containsForbiddenName = forbiddenWordList.stream()
     .anyMatch(forbiddenName -> name.toLowerCase()
          .contains(forbiddenName.toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: changed to method reference name::contains

Comment: answer without any explanation is not very good ... and DOES NOT WORK because LATE will not appear in "Late" whereas the user says it have to find it, it has to be case insensitive

Comment: and it becames same as mine ^^ even mine is a method to avoid code redundance

Answer (score 3):

1. turn the list to a string with the | delimiter

   String listDelimited = String.join("|", forbiddenWordList )
2. create the regex

   Pattern forbiddenWordPattern
           = Pattern.compile(listDelimited , Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
3. test your text

   boolean hasForbiddenWord = forbiddenWordPattern.matcher(text).find();

(similar to the answer of @Maurice Perry)

Comment: For `String name = "Jhon Solomon";` Returns `true`. But I expected `false` here, because there is no word 'SO' there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this :

**Iteration over words** (`stream`) and returns true if any words (named `w`) match with the condition (`contains`)

```
public static boolean isForbidden(String word, List<String> words) {
     return words.stream().anyMatch(w -> (word.toLowerCase().contains(w.toLowerCase())));
}
```

---

**Using regex**, it will build the pattern itself from the `List`

```
public static boolean isForbidden1(String word, List<String> words) {
     String forbiddenWordPattern = String.join("|", words);

     return Pattern.compile(forbiddenWordPattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
                   .matcher(word)
                   .find();
 }
```

Comment: (not the downvoter) - your way to build the pattern is very convoluted, especially as you are already using `Collectors.joining`. There is no need to manually add the separator and remove the first one afterwards. The entire creation of the `forbiddenWordPattern` can be replaced by `String.join("|", words);`

Comment: @Hulk I didn't know String.join("|", words) until see it in a post above

Comment: Alternatively, if you prefer the stream for some reason, use [`Collectors.joining(CharSequence delimiter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-)

Answer (score 2):

The list can be expressed as a pattern:

```
Pattern forbiddenWordPattern
        = Pattern.compile("LATE|S/O|SO|W/O|WO", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

To test the presence of a word in a text, you would do:

```
boolean hasForbiddenWord = forbiddenWordPattern.matcher(text).find();
```

Comment: this loses all the benefits of using a list, if the user wants to add easily a thousands forbiddens words, he don't want to add all to the pattern

Comment: @azro yes, but the question ends "Regular Expression highly appreciated."

Comment: yes it is not an easy solution, look below i have add one which allow to build the pattern automaticly

Comment: For `String name = "Jhon Solomon";` Returns `true`. But I expected `false` here, because there is no word 'SO' there.